# Making a Slick query that filters from an optional id?

Tags: scala, slick

I would like to query an object by `id`, but if a `fooId` is also provided then I'd like to include it in the query.

```
def getById(id: Long, fooIdOpt: Option[Long]): Future[Option[Bar]] = {
  val query = for {
    b <- bars if b.id === id && fooIdOpt.fold(true)(b.fooId === _)
  } yield {            // Compiler error here ^
    b
  }
  db.run(query.result.headOption)
}
```

The issue here is that `fooIdOpt.fold(true)(b.fooId === _)` needs to return a `Rep[Boolean]`, but I'm initializing the fold with a `Boolean` - a clear type violation of `fold`'s method signature.

However I can't seem to find a way to pass a `Rep[Boolean]` that evaluates to `true` in as the fold initializer. Shooting in the dark, I've tried `Rep(true)`, and `LiftedLiteral[Boolean](true)`, but neither quite work.

I could abandon `fold` entirely and go with:

```
b <- bars if {
  val rep1 = b.id === id
  fooIdOpt.map(fooId => rep1 && b.fooId === fooId).getOrElse(rep1)
}
```

But that just seems so overly complicated, and a `fooIdOpt match { case Some ...` wouldn't look much better.

1. Is there a way to instantiate a `Rep[Boolean]` literal that always evaluates to `true`?
2. If not, is there an alternative to my attempts at `fold`, `map`, or `match` above that will allow me to build a query that optionally compares a `fooId` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already figured out, the `ifEmpty` value type for `fold` needs to match that of `b.fooId === _`, which is `Rep[Boolean]`.  One approach would be to apply `bind` to the `ifEmpty` value as shown below:

```
val query = for {
  b <- bars if b.id === id && fooIdOpt.fold(true.bind)(b.fooId === _)
} yield b
```

Comment: This is exactly the method I was looking for! I was sure Slick must provide something that does exactly this, but just didn't know what it was called.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that isn't *quite* as bad as your other options:

```
(fooIdOpt.toList.map(b.fooId === _) :+ (b.id === id)).reduceLeft(_ && _)
```